# Creating dynamic keyvalue pairs within a config section

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I'm writing a class to describe a config section and I'm looking for a possible method to cater to the following scenario:

```
<plugins>
    <add name="resize" maxheight="500px" maxwidth="500px"/>
    <add name="watermark" font="arial"/>
</plugins>
```

Where each item in the list can contain different properties as well as the required name property. Setting up the default section is simple enough but I'm now stuck as how to add the dynamic key/value pairs. Any ideas?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a PluginElementCollection collection configuration element 
    /// within the configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public class PluginElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a PluginConfig configuration element within the 
        /// configuration.
        /// </summary>
        public class PluginElement : ConfigurationElement
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the token of the plugin file.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The name of the plugin.</value>
            [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
            public string Name
            {
                get { return (string)this["name"]; }

                set { this["name"] = value; }
            }

            // TODO: What goes here to create a series of dynamic 
            // key/value pairs.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new PluginConfig configuration element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A new PluginConfig configuration element.
        /// </returns>
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new PluginElement();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the element key for a specified PluginElement 
        /// configuration element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">
        /// The <see cref="T:System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement"/> 
        /// to return the key for.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The element key for a specified PluginElement configuration element.
        /// </returns>
        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((PluginElement)element).Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568454/code-required-to-use-foreach-on-my-own-custom-appsettings/2568780#2568780). Note that you may need to replace SystemConfiguguration with System.Configuration as I was using a `using`-alias to resolve a naming conflict.

Comment: @Morten Mertner - Looking at your code it appears to handle just a default scenario where you know beforehand the key/values. I want to be able to add custom pairs for each instance.

Comment: No, the code is for a completely custom config section containing a list of elements. You may obviously need to modify some bits as you want to store different values, but the classes needed are all there.

Comment: Yeah in `UserElement` Which is exactly where I am asking the equivalent question. I need to add something to `PluginElement`.

Comment: You just add the desired properties to your PluginElement class and decorate them with `[ConfigurationElement(Required=false)]` to make them optional. You cannot (afaik) use the built-in configuration subsystem to make your data completely dynamic, so you must specify the available options on your class in advance.

Comment: You can use the [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx) if you don't want a schema associated with your section. It will provide read-only access to the contained XML structure. Unfortunately, this is an all or nothing approach (cannot be used on a part of a section). Also note that the interface was deprecated in .NET 2.0 (but continues to work fine).

Comment: Man that sucks! Thanks.. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I have some code that implements IConfigurationSectionHandler along with bits to annotate classes in order to automatically extract the desired config parts. It's all read-only but could provide a starting point. Shoot me a PM if you want a copy.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up using a further nested ConfigurationElementCollection as a property of each plugin. It actually makes it easier to read in the web.config too.

Comment: @James post your answer for the world to see

Answer (score 5):

In your `ConfigurationElement` you can override `OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute()` and then store the extra attributes somewhere, in a Dictionary for example:

```
public class PluginElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; private set; }

    public PluginElement ()
    {
        Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    protected override bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        Attributes.Add(name, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Returning `true` from `OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute` indicates that you've handled the unrecongnized attribute, and prevents the `ConfigurationElement` base class from throwing an exception, which it normally does when you haven't declared a `[ConfigurationProperty]` for every attribute in the config xml.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a go and report back.